# C# Display Join Query in DataGridView at designTime using TableAdapter, etc

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, join, tableadapter

I have a DataGridView

I also have some tableAdapters (groupTableAdapter, userTableAdapter) generated from sqlserver database.

I have created a JOIN query in userTableAdapter that shows users with their correspoding groupname.

Of course, I've got the classic warning Visual Studio throws regarding it is not the original bla bla bla... after I generated the Fill and Get methods in the tableAdapter

I'd like to know if there's a way (using these objects), to assign this JOIN query "at designtime" on the DataGridView, so I can visually reorder and/or hide some columns in the grid. Or would be better creating an storedproc? or anything else? and how?

And also, how can I do the same and assign that JOIN query to a bindingNavigator which should be linked to the grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer
I've created a new TableAdapter in my DataSet. This new tableAdapter allows me to use a query to return rows. **I used a join query, created the Fill and Get methods, and done. So simple, but do hard to find**